# WPF setting up Video player from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, media-player, viewmodel

I am working on a WPF application. I need a player to play a file but I need the player in ViewModel as I need it to create snapshot on the player from the ViewModel. This is not working as I can hear the sound but the video is blank.

What am I Missing.

```
<ContentControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{DynamicResource IconSnapShot}" />
```

Full XAML

```
 <Window x:Class="TestPlayer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestPlayer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
     <Grid>
           <Grid>
               <ContentControl Content="{Binding PlayerFrameworkElement, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Visibility="{Binding PlayerVisibility}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red"/>
          </Grid>
     </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel

```
  using Gu.Wpf.Media;
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  public class PlayerModelView : NotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private MediaElementWrapper playerFrameworkElement = new MediaElementWrapper();
    private Uri sourcePath;

    public PlayerModelView()
    {
        this.SourcePath = new Uri(@"J:\file.mkv", UriKind.Absolute);
    }
    public Uri SourcePath
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sourcePath;
        }

        set
        {
            this.sourcePath = value;
            this.PlayerFrameworkElement.Source = null;
            this.PlayerFrameworkElement.Source = value;
        }
    }
    public MediaElementWrapper PlayerFrameworkElement
    {
        get
        {
            return this.playerFrameworkElement;
        }

        set
        {
            this.playerFrameworkElement = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.PlayerFrameworkElement);
        }
    }

 }
}
```

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
//
// 
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#region

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

#endregion

/// <summary>
///     The notify property changed.
/// </summary>
public abstract class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Public Events

    /// <summary>
    ///     The property changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    ///     The raise property changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyExpression">
    ///     The property expression.
    /// </param>
    /// <typeparam name="TProperty">
    /// </typeparam>
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body;
        var propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     The raise property changed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">
    ///     The property name.
    /// </param>
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: You must add a `MediaElement` to the visual tree for the video to get rendered. It makes no sense to create a `UIElement` in the view model.

Comment: In need it there so that I can capture the image from the video.

Comment: don't use any visual content in your view model, just bind your necessary data, develop custom control for it